# Equivalent of virtual method for a container of base class pointers?

Tags: c++, polymorphism, c++14

Note: this post is light on code as it's focused on concepts; I intend to rewrite fairly large portions of the relevant code I have based on the conclusions reached here, so showing large amounts of code would just make the post even longer, for no good reason IMO.

**Summary:**

I don't think I can write a short version that works on its own (I tried, and it wasn't short at all), so I'll begin with a summary of the main goal.

I need some sort of equivalent of implementing a virtual method on a container of object pointers.
Currently, I have something like `virtual object::performAction(action someAction)`, which works just fine for calling on one object at once. However, I now need an equivalent where the action can be performed on multiple instances of `object` at once (where the instances may be of various derived classes, mixed together). That is, something that is conceptually equivalent to `virtual vector<object*>::performAction(action someAction)`; the method needs access to all `object`s as once, so calling the current implementation in a foreach loop over the vector won't cut it.

For reasons detailed below, I don't believe I can simply create a virtual method such as `action::performAction(vector<object*>)`, at least not in a clean and type safe way.

**Details:**

I'm working on an application which is a kind of launcher/local search application, that allows for as-you-type searching of various items.
It has two important concepts:
1) Objects (e.g. songs, files, applications), or more generally: things the user might search for, that you can perform actions of some kind on. These are currently subclasses of an abstract base class, call it `object`.
2) Actions (e.g. play, enqueue, open with default application, run, show in file manager): things the user might want to do to an object. These are currently represented by strings, but that'll probably have to change to solve this question.

Right now, you can only select one object at a time. After selecting an object, a virtual method `selectedObject->getActions()` is called; those actions are displayed, the user selects an action from that list, and finally something like `selectedObject->performAction(selectedAction)` is called.
I want to extend this so that you can perform an action on multiple objects as once. That is, the user selects 1 *or more* objects, selects an action that applies to all of them, and the action executes, once, on all objects.
I suppose I will have to flip this around: instead of `selectedObject->performAction(selectedAction)`, I might have to do `selectedAction->performActionOnObjects(selectedObjects)`, where selectedAction is a base class pointer, and each type of action is its own subclass of action (`playaction`, `enqueueaction`, `runaction` etc).

I'm not sure how to implement this, however. Each action should only accept a few object types: you can play songs, but not applications. On the other hand, a given action *should* allow more than one object type: you can play both songs and albums, yet songs and albums are represented as different `object` subclasses.

The only approach I can think of is to use interfaces (multiple inheritance in C++?), i.e. `albumobject` derives from both `object` and some kind of `IPlayable`-ish abstract class, but I'm not sure how to implement that in practice. I also don't know if that's a good way to solve this or not.
Specifically, I'm not sure how to figure out which `object`s implement IPlayable, at runtime (without casts), or how to get by without that knowledge.
If this is the road taken, it seems to me that each "interface" needs to declare methods to fetch action-specific information (song URLs for albums, path + arguments for executing applications, etc). Herein lies the catch 22.
If an action like `playaction::performActionOnObjects` takes a `vector<object*>` as an argument, it will accept all object classes, regardless of whether the "play" action makes sense for them or not.
If instead it takes interface pointers, such as `playaction::performActionOnObjects(vector<IPlayable*>)`, I don't know how to properly call it, since all I will have at the call site is a vector of `object*`. Some of them may implement IPlayable, but many will not. I can easily figure out which implement the action (via a virtual method on the `object`), but would have to cast them to call the action method, right?

So, in short:
* Each `object` may have multiple actions (e.g. albums have play, enqueue and a few others)
* Each `action` may or may not support multiple `object` types (you can play both songs and albums, but the only runnable object type is application)
* All objects we want to operate on, regardless of type, are stored together in a container of base pointers (specifically as `QVector<shared_ptr<object>>`)

How do I implement this in a clean way?
Preferably in such a way that future application plugins can define additional actions and/or object types without touching the main application's code.
I've been reading up a bit on the visitor pattern, but don't quite "get" it yet, so I'm not sure if it could apply here, and if so, how to implement it.

**UPDATE:**

Here's some example code. Note that **this may be the wrong approach**, and that the question is how to **not** do this.

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

// Classes which implement this can be sent to playaction::performActionOnObjects(...)
class IPlayable {
public:
    virtual vector<string> getTrackURLs() = 0;
};

class object {
public:
    virtual string getName() = 0;
};

class albumobject : public object, public IPlayable {
public:
    string getName() override { return "some album"; }
    vector<string> getTrackURLs() override { return { "file:///track/1", "file:///track/2" }; };
};

class applicationobject : public object {
public:
    string getName() override { return "some application"; }
    string getExecutablePath() { return "/usr/bin/application"; }
};

class action {
public:
    virtual void performActionOnObjects(vector<object*> objects) = 0;
};

class playaction : public action {
public:
    void performActionOnObjects(vector<object*> objects) override {
        vector<string> allUrls;
        for (object *obj : objects) {
            // Not possible: object doesn't implement getTrackURLs
            // dynamic_cast to IPlayable* required; is there a better way?
            auto tmp = obj->getTrackURLs();
            allUrls.insert(end(allUrls), begin(tmp), end(tmp));
        }
        // Do something with allUrls...
    }
};

int main() {
    vector<object*> objects { new albumobject, new albumobject };
    playaction action;
    action.performActionOnObjects(objects);

    return 0;
}
```

If I instead define
`playaction::performActionOnObjects(vector<IPlayable*> objects)`
that just shifts the problem to main(), where I want to pass a `vector<object*>` to a method that needs a `vector<IPlayable*>`, unless I'm missing something crucial.
Therefore, I'm looking for some way to decouple this a bit further, so I can avoid casts in both locations.

Comment: Would it be possible to create an SSCCE that demonstrates why `performAction(vector<object*>)` is not feasible? (I don't want to read through that wall of test, sorry). Also, why does this function need access to all selected objects at once? Do they have interdependencies or are you planning on executing the actions concurrently? Short of some such requirement, a `for` loop that executes the action on each selected item seems to be exactly what you need.

Comment: @Praetorian Yeah, sorry about the length; I wasn't sure how to keep it down while also not wasting others' time by having them write non-applicable answers. In short, that solution probably won't work (cleanly) because `performAction` needs access to methods that are defined in interfaces that only *some* `object`s use. I could probably use a dynamic_cast<interface*> inside the method, but I'm looking for a cleaner solution. `performAction(vector<interface*>)` will just move the problem to the call site, as far as I can tell.

Comment: @exscape I couldn't quite grok your comment. Wouldn't it be possible to create a dummy hierarchy with a handful of classes illustrating your issues?

Comment: If all selected objects can't perform an action, why is that action selectable for those objects? In otherwords, given a list of objects, I would be expected to be presented with the common subset of functionality they can all perform, not the union of all of their possible actions.

Comment: What does it mean exactly to access all objects at once? Can you illustrate it with a vector of objects of the same type? Why accessing these objects in a loop doesn't qualify?

Comment: @aruisdante Yes, that is how it works; the intersection of actions is presented to the user, and the user selects one. However, the list of selected items is stored as base pointers. If I pass those base pointers to performAction, it can only access base methods, but it needs to call methods from derived classes (from an interface-like class). I'll try to write up a code example soon.

Comment: @Praetorian I added a code example. The main reason for needing all objects as once is concurrent execution, such as creating an external process once, with 100 arguments, instead of creating 100 processes. Other reasons may show up in the future.

Comment: Your example is still missing how you select the objects that some action is to be performed on from the set of all objects that exist in your program. The complexity should probably be moved to that location as Ben says in his answer.

Comment: @Praetorian That part is already solved in (IMO) a pretty nice way. The user selects the objects to use in the GUI; when the user moves over to the "select action" list,  `virtual vector<string> object::getActions()` is called on each selected object; only the actions common to all objects are then displayed, so any action selected by the user is valid. (If no action is valid, a warning shows up.)

Answer (score 0):

Unless I misunderstood your question, I have a possible solution in mind.

**Use composition, instead of inheritance.**

- Use a bitset to keep track of "object features".
- Object may or not may have a specific component (a "feature").
- Use a manager to query objects.

---

```
// An instance of this bitset will be stored in every object
// to keep track of its available components
constexpr std::size_t objectTypeCount{2};
using ObjectBitset = std::bitset<objectTypeCount>;

// Bit 0: ComponentPlayable availability 
constexpr std::size_t bitPlayable{0};

// Bit 1: ComponentExecutable availability 
constexpr std::size_t bitExecutable{1};

// Note: objects can be both playable and executable at the same time
//       using this component-based design

// A component is a class with data and logic
struct ComponentPlayable
{
    // Could also store a reference to the parent object here
    // to allow easier communication between components in the 
    // same object

    int lengthInSeconds;
    void play() { /* ... */ }
};

struct ComponentExecutable
{
    std::string targetArchitecture;
    bool permissionsAvailable;
    void execute() { /* ... */ }
};

// An object is just a container of components
struct Object
{
    ObjectBitset types;

    // Obviously a more clever way of storing/creating/querying
    // components could be used
    std::unique_ptr<ComponentPlayable> cPlayable;
    std::unique_ptr<ComponentExecutable> cExecutable;

    // Constructing and initializing a component sets the appropriate
    // bit to true
    template<typename... Ts> void initCPlayable(Ts&&... xs)
    {
        cPlayable = std::make_unique<ComponentPlayable>(std::forward<Ts>(xs)...);
        types[bitPlayable] = true;
    }

    template<typename... Ts> void initCExecutable(Ts&&... xs)
    {
        cExecutable = std::make_unique<ComponentExecutable>(std::forward<Ts>(xs)...);
        types[bitExecutable] = true;
    }

    // Object component availability can be checked quickly
    // thanks to the bitset
    bool isPlayable() { return types[bitPlayable]; }
    bool isExecutable() { return types[bitExecutable]; }

    // Note: checking component availability could have been done
    //       by comparing the stored unique_ptr with nullptr as well,
    //       but using bitset allows for quicker checks for specific
    //       object signatures (has this object component X, Y and Z?)
    //       and also assigning a specific unique bit to components 
    //       can make it much easier to design efficient data structures
    //       for component storage and object querying
};

struct Manager
{
    std::vector<Object> objects;

    // Could also dynamically add/remove objects to buckets
    // based on the components they have to speed up querying

    template<typename TF> void execOnPlayables(TF mFn)
    {        
        for(auto& o : objects) 
            if(o.isPlayable()) 
            { 
                assert(o.cPlayable != nullptr); 
                mFn(*o.cPlayable);
            }
    }

    template<typename TF> void execOnExecutables(TF mFn)
    {        
        for(auto& o : objects) 
            if(o.isExecutable()) 
            { 
                assert(o.cExecutable != nullptr); 
                mFn(*o.cExecutable);
            }
    }
};

int main()
{
    Manager m;
    // Fill manager here...

    m.execOnPlayables([](auto& mC){ mC.play(); });
    m.execOnExecutables([](auto& mC){ mC.execute(); });
}
```

---

Some benefits of a component-oriented design:

- Objects do not have to follow a specific inheritance tree
- Objects can have multiple components (features)
- Objects can be queried on their components easily (execute this functions on all objects that are *playable* and *executable*, but that are not *removable*)

Comment: "Use a bitset to keep track of object features." is very difficult to extend.  You cannot add new features without making changes to all the existing objects.

Comment: I disagree. Adding new components and extending objects can be very easy with the correct design. The example I posted is focused on simplicity. You could [take a look at my (still naive) implementation for a gamedev-oriented component system](https://github.com/SuperV1234/SSVEntitySystem). Adding and querying components is pretty straightforward. An even better implementation could, for example, take all component types as variadic parameter pack in the `Manager` class, and automatically generate the required bitsets and data structures.

Answer (score 0):

Let `getActions` return a container of `pair<action_id, std::function<void ()>`, with the function object already bound to the more derived subobject.

Comment: Doesn't this mean all actions must be a function that take no arguments and return no value. How would it work for `getTrackURLs`?

Comment: Not a function, a closure object, which can store data such as the identity of the object. And it doesn't have to be zero parameters.  But generic handling of a wide variety of actions does ultimately require that they all conform to some common signature.

Comment: @BenVoigt Hm, could you expand a bit on this? getActions is implemented for each item individually right now (object has `virtual vector<string> getActions() = 0`, so each type overrides it). If I do this, won't the method be called on one object at a time, rather than on all of them at once (which is the entire goal)?

Comment: The functions get invoked one at a time, yes, but they don't have to perform the action immediately. They can perform setup operations, like adding object pointers of the correct type to the list of targets.

Comment: I still basically don't have a clue how to implement this; it sounds promising, but I'm unused to this kind of programming style. Should the function pointer/closure be one from an Action class, or a lambda created in getActions that does the setup? Where does it save the list of action function/object pairs for that object, and later on, how do I go from a list of `object*` to a list of such pairs, and then finally to a list of derived class pointers I can e.g. send to an external application?  
A rather short example could probably take care of almost every question.

Answer (score 0):

You could have some sort of action [Visitor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern). The visitor visits all the items that have been selected to be acted upon and then as long as they all meet the requirements the action is performed on all all the items:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

class Object;
class Application;
class Song;

struct IPlayable {
  virtual void play() = 0;
};

struct ActionVisitor {
  virtual void visit(Application&) = 0;
  virtual void visit(Song&) = 0; 
};

struct Object {
  virtual void accept(ActionVisitor&) = 0;
};
struct Application : Object {
  void accept(ActionVisitor& visitor) override { visitor.visit(*this); }
};
struct Song : IPlayable, Object {
  std::string name;

  Song(std::string name) : name(std::move(name)) {}
  void accept(ActionVisitor& visitor) override { visitor.visit(*this); }
  void play() override { std::cout << "Playing " << name << "\n"; }
};

class PlayVisitor : public ActionVisitor {
  std::vector<IPlayable*> queue;
  bool playable;
 public:
  void visit(Application&) override { playable = false; }
  void visit(Song& song) override { queue.push_back(&song); }
  void play(std::vector<Object*>& objects) {
    playable = true;
    queue.clear();
    for(auto& object : objects)
       object->accept(*this); 
    if (playable) {
      for(auto object : queue) object->play(); 
    }
  };
};

int main() {
  Song song1("Song1");
  Song song2("Song2");
  Application app1;

  std::vector<Object*> selected_playable{&song1, &song2};
  PlayVisitor player;
  player.play(selected_playable);

  std::vector<Object*> unplayable{&song2, &app1};
  player.play(unplayable);
}
```

<kbd>[Live demo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/sLgnrxtslXPxFHWq)</kbd>

As always with the Visitor pattern, the visitor violates the [open/closed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle) principle because it has to have visit functions for all possible objects but it might be a price worth paying.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to discriminate between the type of action performed on an object, you could simply add `virtual void run()=0;` to your Base class and implement the object specific actions in their own classes. 
If you want to perform a certain action on all objects from a vector of objects who support this action, you will have to implement some type of capability testing.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

enum{
    OBJ,
    AUDIO,
    TXT
};
struct object
{
    int type;
    virtual void run(){cout<<"playAction will not show this\n";}
    object() : type(OBJ){}
};
struct audiofile : public object
{
    virtual void run()  {cout<<"playing audio file\n";}
    audiofile()  {type = AUDIO;}
};
void playAction(object* obj) {
    if (obj->type==AUDIO)
        obj->run();
}
int main() {
    audiofile a, b, c;
    object d, e, f;
    vector<object*> objList = {&a,&b,&c,&d,&e,&f};
    for(object* o: objList){
        playAction(o);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

You can use a lot of different approaches to achieve the same thing, another approach would be to use `typeid` to check the object type. Just apply these changes to playAction in the example above:

```
void playAction(object* obj) {
    if (typeid(*obj)==typeid(audiofile))
        obj->run();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following seem to work. 
It requires RTTI.

```
template< typename DerivedT, typename ContainerT, typename MemberFunctionT,typename ...ParamTs >
void perform_on_all( ContainerT& cont, MemberFunctionT func, ParamTs ...params )
{
    for( auto&& itm : cont )
    {
        DerivedT* d = dynamic_cast<DerivedT*>(itm);
        if(d) (d->*func)(params...);
    }
}

struct Base
{
    virtual ~Base() {}
};

struct Test : public Base
{
    virtual void Foo() =0;
    virtual void Bar(int) =0;
};

void testit()
{
    vector<Base*> tvec;

    perform_on_all<Test>( tvec, &Test::Foo );
    perform_on_all<Test>( tvec, &Test::Bar, 3 );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because I'm a bit of a git, I like reimplementing RTTI.

```
template<class...>struct types{using type=types;};
template<class X>struct tag{using type=X;};
```

is a collection of types.

```
template<class X>
class get_interface_base {
  virtual X* get_interface( tag<X> ) { return nullptr; };
  virtual X const* get_interface( tag<X> ) const { return nullptr; };
};
template<class types>
struct interfaces {
  virtual ~interfaces() {};
  void get_interface() {
    static_assert(false,
      "use the free function I* get_interface<I>(*this) please."
    );
  }
};
template<class X, class...Xs>
struct interfaces<types<X,Xs...>:
  get_interface_base<X>,
  interfaces<types<Xs...>>
{
  using get_interface_base<X>::get_interface;
  using interfaces<types<Xs...>>::get_interface;
};
```

and now we have our interface casts:

```
namespace details {
  template<class I, class X>
  I* get_interface( X& x, std::false_type /*is_const*/ ) {
    return x.get_interface( tag<Tag>{} );
  }
  template<class I, class X>
  I const* get_interface( X const& x, std::true_type /*is_const*/ ) {
    return x.get_interface( tag<Tag>{} );
  }
}
// use: Playable* p = get_interface<Playable>(*foo);
template<class I, class X>
typename std::conditional<std::is_const<X>::value, I const, I>::type*
get_interface( X& x ) {
  using is_const = std::integral_constant<bool,
    std::is_const<X>::value || std::is_const<I>::value
  >;
  typename I2 = typename std::remove_const<I>::type;
  return details::get_interface<I2>(x, is_const{});
}
// function object version:
template<class I>
struct get_interface_t {
  template<class T>
  I* operator()(T* t)const{
    if (!t) return nullptr;
    return (*this)(*t);
  }
  template<class T>
  I* operator()(T& t)const{
    return get_interface<I>(t);
  }
};
```

which gives us a compile-time determined list of interfaces and a single virtual table lookup to get an interface from a class.

You maintain a global `using supported_types = types< Playable, Chickenable, Deletable >;` somewhere, and your base class inherits from `interfaces<supported_types>` publicly.  Attempt to `get_interface<Foo>` if `Foo` is not in `supported_types` fails at compile time.  `const` is supported smartly.

The interfaces supported by an instance can be exposed via indexes into the `supported_types` list of types.  We can write `index_of<T, types<?...>>` to compare said integers to the types in question.

To go the other way, we can magic switch.

A transformer from `std::vector<T*>` to `std::vector<I*>`:

```
template<class I>
struct get_interfaces_t {
  template<class Ts>
  std::vector<I*> operator()( Ts&& ts )const{
    std::vector<I*> retval;
    using std::begin; using std::end;
    std::tranform( begin(ts), end(ts), std::inserter(retval, retval.end()),
      get_interface_t<I>{}
    );
    return retval;
  }
};
```

a magic switch, that takes a list of types `types<Is...>` a run time value i, a transformer `Z`, a function object `F` and a generic thing `T`, and invokes `F( Z<I>(T) )` where `I` is the ith type in `Is...`.  It returns `false` if `i` is out of bounds.

```
template<class types, template<class>class Z>
struct magic_switch_t;
template<class...Is, template<class>class Z>
struct magic_switch_t<types<Is...>> {
  template<class T, class F>
  bool operator()(size_t i, T&& t, F&& f)const {
    typedef void(*f)( T&&, F&& );
    static f arr[] = {
      [](T&& t, F&& f){
        std::forward<F>(f)( Z<Is>{}(std::forward<T>(t)) );
      }...
    };
    if ( i >= sizeof...(Is) )
      return false;
    arr[i]( std::forward<T>(t), std::forward<F>(f) );
    return true;
  }
};
```

some compilers that claim to be C++11 fail on the above code.

Now, we can query your objects for supported interfaces, find a supported one, and then use magic switch to invoke a function (say, one taking a vector of `I*`) on it.

`F` above should have overloads for every `std::vector<I*>` even the ones that do not support the operation.  They can simply do nothing.  We could presume that the `F` returns a `bool` return value, and have that error propagate out if we choose with a bit of a code change.

If the system supports partial application (ie, play when only 1 of 2 files are music), then the `std::vector<I*>` will contain null pointers for the ones that the operation does not apply to.

A function object for playing might read:

```
struct play_stuff_t {
  std::true_type operator()( std::vector<Playable const*> const& targets ) const {
    do_play( targets );
    return {};
  }
  template<class X>
  std::false_type operator()( std::vector<X const*> const& ) const {
    return {};
  }
};
```

where `do_play` is a free function that supports playing a vector of playables.

Summary:

- Create your own more efficient RTTI that operates on a fixed list of types.
- Expose capabilities as indexes into the above fixed list of types.  These can be a vector of indexes, or bits in a bitfield, whatever.
- Determine capabilities of your list of elements
- When you invoke, use `magic_switch` to turn that into a compile-time type and map your list of elements to a list of the appropriate interface

Finally, note that while `get_interface<Blah>` might look like a cast, an object could return a pointer to *anything* -- itself as that interface, as sub-object, or even a global object of some kind.  We could even add lifetime management to the returned pointer if we want to polish things off (which allows a class to return a temporary interface object on that call).

We can also write a CRTP class that, given a class `X`, a bundle of types `Is...`, and a set of bases `Bs...`, inherits from `Bs...` and implements the `get_interface`s by casting itself as an `X` implicitly to the interface type.  This class is far easier to write if we make the inheritance from each `get_interface_base` `virtual` (it gets rid of the requirement to pass `Bs...` through, and makes the linear unfolding of inheritance far easier).